# Reproducible vs. Replicable

Tags: word-choice, differences

What is the difference between *replicable* and *reproducible*?

I want to know which word should be used to indicate whether a technical problem or error can be repeated by following a defined set of steps.

However, when I google for the difference between these two terms, I get lengthy articles discussing these terms in a scientific context.

Comment: *Reproduce* is the term normally used. You might use *replicate* to indicate that you reproduced a problem exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Reproducible*** implies that something can be recreated by iterating through steps to get an identical result as was received initially.

***Replicable*** implies that something can be duplicated, essentially.

In this situation, *Reproducible* would be the recommended word to use.